# When to call KafkaProducer close method?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

As Kafka document said that,

> The producer is thread safe and sharing a single producer instance
>   across threads will generally be faster than having multiple
>   instances.

So I have following code and want to only have one instance of KafkaProducer for each send request. But when is the best place in the code to call close method on it? As I can't call close method in the send method. How should I write the code to handle?

```
public class Producer {
    private final KafkaProducer<Integer, String> producer;

    public Producer(String topic, Boolean isAsync) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, KafkaProperties.KAFKA_SERVER_URL + ":" + KafkaProperties.KAFKA_SERVER_PORT);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "DemoProducer");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerSerializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
    }

    public void send(String message) {
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic, messageNo, messageStr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the producer first and pass(inject) it to your web resource or resources.

Then you can use a shutdown hook to close the producer with its reference.

Even better if you can use life cycle stop hooks in your framework.
Example in dropwizard:
https://www.dropwizard.io/en/latest/manual/core.html?highlight=managed#managed-objects

Answer (score 0):

Kafka [producer](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html) implements the AutoClosable interface. So you can declare it within the try-with-resources block, and it should take care of releasing the resources when your code goes outside the scope of the block.

Comment: I don't want to close on producer each time after send has been called otherwise I have to create a producer instance each time.

Comment: Are you using multiple threads? If yes, then are they runnable or callable? Are they perpetually running? If possible, please update your question with these information.

Comment: not multiple threads, only single. But there is a POST endpoint and each time has been called will call the `send` method here. If for that case, when is the time to do `close`?

Comment: If it's a perpetually running app, then invoking the `close()` method might not make much sense.

Comment: Yeah, it's a Spring boot web app. So no need to call `close` method?

Comment: I think so. In our production, we have a rest based app that ingests data to Kafka, and I'm pretty sure it's never closed. So far we haven't seen any resource leak associated with the producer, so should be fine.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. That's what I want to know. I am also thinking to implement a `Closeable` interface of my `Producer` class if there are some resources leaking.

Answer (score 0):

Do you ever need to change producer parameters at runtime? For example when changing the broker urls or during tests?

If you need it and you have a singletone producer, make sure to provide a hook to close and recreate the producer with new parameters.